# Problem inserting XML parsed data in MySQL tabel

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am trying to parse XML using PHP DOM and then insert this data in MySQL tables, i am using the following code for this:

```
<?php
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("testrtap11.xml");
mysql_select_db("zeeshan_database1", $con);

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('RECORD');
$z=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('TITLE');
$w=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('PRIMARY_AUTHOR');
$y=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('JOURNAL_CONFERENCE');

for($i=0; $i<=$x->length-1; $i++)
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES('$z->item($i)->nodeValue','$w->item($i)->nodeValue','$y->item($i)->nodeValue')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "1 record added";
}

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

The data being entered is not correct. i even tried storing my xml parse values in a variable and then using that variable to insert data, even that does not works. I used the variable like this:

```
for($i=0; $i<=$x->length-1; $i++)
{
    $zz=$z->item($i)->nodeValue);
    $ww=$w->item($i)->nodeValue);
    $yy=$y->item($i)->nodeValue);
    $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES('$zz','$ww','$yy')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "1 record added";
}
```

My xml looks like this:

```
<RTAP>
  <RECORD>
     <TITLE>               </TITLE>
     <PRIMARY_AUTHOR>      </PRIMARY_AUTHOR>
     <JOURNAL_CONFERENCE>  </JOURNAL_CONFERENCE>
  </RECORD>
</RTAP>
```

Kindly help me, what should I do in this

Best
Zeeshan

Comment: Can you please include the data that you were expecting to be stored and the data that was actually stored?

Comment: Have you tried debugging or printing values first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
foreach ($xmlDoc->RECORD as $record)
{
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES('
        . '"' . mysql_escape_string($record->TITLE->nodeValue) . '", '
        . '"' . mysql_escape_string($record->PRIMARY_AUTHOR->nodeValue) . '", '
        . '"' . mysql_escape_string($record->JOURNAL_CONFERENCE->nodeValue) . '")'

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

    echo "1 record added";
}
```

You don't actually say what's wrong with the data that's inserted...

Comment: I tried using the select command:
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
  echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
  echo "<br />";
 }

And this is the output i got:
(0)->nodeValue (0)->nodeValue
(1)->nodeValue (1)->nodeValue
(2)->nodeValue (2)->nodeValue
(3)->nodeValue (3)->nodeValue

Comment: Greg what is the $record that you have mentioned in your code?
is it like $z->item($i)->nodeValue that i am using in mine code. 

But the thing is your statement is not working for some reason-- i cant not figure out..

Comment: Hey greg thanks, your code did work out after just a few changes in it. 
thanks alot. 
Zeeshan

Comment: Oops, I'd made a complete mess of the quotes

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the select command on my original code that i mentioned above: 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName']; 
echo "
"; 
}

And this is the output i got: 
(0)->nodeValue (0)->nodeValue 
(1)->nodeValue (1)->nodeValue 
(2)->nodeValue (2)->nodeValue 
(3)->nodeValue (3)->nodeValue